# Split line into 3 separate arguments using xargs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs

If I have the following:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}"

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

where each line is a new array element. I want to be able to split the element by space delimiter and use the result as 3 separate parameters and pipe into xargs.

For example the first element is:

```
1 2 3
```

where using xargs I want to pass `1`, `2` and `3` into a simple echo command such as:

```
$ echo $0
1
4
7

$ echo $1
2
5
8

$ echo $2
3
9
6
```

So I have been trying doing this in the following way:

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3 | xargs -d' ' -n 3 bash -c 'echo $0'
```

which gives:

```
1
2
3 4
5
6 7
8
9 10
```

which aside from the strange line ordering - trying `xargs -d' ' -n 3 bash -c 'echo $0'` does not print out the first "element" of each line i.e.

```
$ echo $0
1
4
7
```

but rather prints them all out.

What I am asking is, for each element, how do I split the line into three separate arguments that can be referenced via xargs?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the `10` in the output come from?

Comment: The input file is actually longer (much longer!), same three column format though. I cut it off for convenience of explaining the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You were going in the right direction

To declare an array:

```
fa=('1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9')
```

To achieve what you want:

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}" | xargs -n 3 sh -c 'echo call_my_command --arg1="$1" --arg2="$2" --arg3="$3"' argv0
```

this will echo you the following lines (change command that is passed to the xargs accordingly)

```
call_my_command --arg1=1 --arg2=2 --arg3=3
call_my_command --arg1=4 --arg2=5 --arg3=6
call_my_command --arg1=7 --arg2=8 --arg3=9
```

If I just add your answer and changed it a little we'll get the following

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3 | xargs -n 3 bash -c 'echo $0 $1 $2'
```

notice missing -d' ' in xargs, this option is not available in some versions of xargs.